# How do I display "Not connected" only when my API returns "null" string type in the context of Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js

I have given my code below, my API returns "null" string type currently, so I want to display "Not connected" when my API returns null and "connected" if my API returns other than null.

```
<template>
  <div class="api_data">
    <span class="trick_ok" v-if="status === 'null'" >Not connected</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: Api_data,
  data () {
    return {
      status: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://my_api_goes_here/doubt/')
      .then((response) => { this.status = response.data })
      .catch((error) => { console.log(error) })
  }
}
</script>
```

I want the logic behind this because I'm new to Vuejs, As you can see my code I have given "Not connected" directly without even using any mustache. As I have not used any mustache my console says failed to load resources. But if I use the {{status}} it shows nothing as my API returns "null" string type.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use ternary operator to switch between connected and not connected text based on status as so instead of using v-if(if used needs else span also and your status should be of type string and null as per your given code,if not string then just use v-if="status" and v-else):

```
<div class="api_data">
    <span class="trick_ok">{{this.status=='connected'?'Connected':'Not connected'}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello thank you for responding, will this work ? because currently my API is returning "null" so i want to display it as 'not connected' , only if my API returns something other than null i want to display it has 'connected' , please can you tell me how can i do this by sending example code. 
I tried the answer that you have sent me, but even though my API fails to load the resources it says "Not connected ", which is inappropriate it has to display Not connected or connected only when the resources is loaded from the API.

Comment: just changing the condition as this.status=='null'?'Not connected':'Connected' should be able to work if your status is of null string type or just the condition part as this.status!='null'

Comment: Yes, my status returns "null" string type, so i want to display not connected when it returns null string type and connected if it returns something else, so your answer might work out, i will try and get back to you.